# How to map dynamic lists in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Ok so I am kind of new to flutter, but I trying to fetch and display items in a list using `map`.

```
class TransactionTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TransactionTableState();
  }
}

class TransactionTableState extends State {
  final List moneyTransactions = [
    new MoneyTransactionModel(
        id: "1",
        productId: "lime",
        entryType: "sold",
        quantity: "60kg",
        unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
        paidBy: "mtn",
        createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
    new MoneyTransactionModel(
        id: "2",
        productId: "lime",
        entryType: "sold",
        quantity: "60kg",
        unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
        paidBy: "mtn",
        createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
    new MoneyTransactionModel(
        id: "3",
        productId: "lime",
        entryType: "sold",
        quantity: "60kg",
        unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
        paidBy: "mtn",
        createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
    new MoneyTransactionModel(
        id: "4",
        productId: "lime",
        entryType: "sold",
        quantity: "60kg",
        unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
        paidBy: "mtn",
        createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
  ];
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return 
    return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      moneyTransactions.map((e) => MyListTile()); // i need to the the loop here
    ],
    );
  }
}
```

`MyListTile` is a widget supposed to display  one item in the `moneyTransactions` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a List into an existing `List`, your build method should look like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: moneyTransactions.map((e) => MyListTile()).toList();
    );
}
```

Now for each item in the `List`, one instance of `MyListTile` is generated.

To have actual access to the information of the `MoneyTransaction` you would have to pass the object as a parameter in the constructor of `MyListTile`.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting to lists and that's why it is not working. Also, you need to call `toList()` after the `map()` operation. Try following code:

### Method 1

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // return 
  return Column(
    children: moneyTransactions.map((e) => MyListTile()).toList(),
  );
}
```

### Method 2

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
      ...moneyTransactions.map((e) => MyListTile()).toList(),
    ],
  );
}
```